# Migrating django auto model loading to iPython .11+ - how to execute code after script loads?

Tags: python, django, ipython

I'm having trouble migrating my old iPython `ipy_user_conf.py` script to the new .11+ iPython.

Before, loading models was as easy as [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/549/) in `ipy_user_conf.py`

My `manage.py` sets the django environment so iPython could `import django` successfully regardless of project / not having django on my global site packages.

Now, if I have the new iPython config file execute the same script, I get import errors.

Any suggestions? Aside from `django-extensions shell_plus` (this is my temporary solution).

Comment: It's possible that the config file is getting run before the Django setup - it probably depends on the details of how you're starting it. You might want to try asking the [ipython-user](http://mail.scipy.org/mailman/listinfo/ipython-user) mailing list.